# Permutation lowercase and uppercase in python

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools, uppercase, lowercase

**I want this result but not by string ,by input() and Number of characters unknown!**

```
mystring = 'abcd'
for a in (mystring[0].upper(), mystring[0].lower()):
    for b in (mystring[1].upper(), mystring[1].lower()):
        for c in (mystring[2].upper(), mystring[2].lower()):
            for d in (mystring[3].upper(), mystring[3].lower()):
                print(a+b+c+d)
```

Comment: there's itertools that should give you just that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach using [`swapcase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.swapcase) and itertools.permutation:

```
from itertools import product

mystring = 'abcd'
cases = zip(*[mystring, mystring.swapcase()])
for permutation in product(*cases):
    print("".join(permutation))
```

**Output**

```
abcd
abcD
abCd
abCD
aBcd
aBcD
aBCd
aBCD
Abcd
AbcD
AbCd
AbCD
ABcd
ABcD
ABCd
ABCD
```